# Vim plugin installation saying that I have to check my access rights

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system

I'm using a plugin manager Vim Plug and I'm trying to install YouCompleteMe but I keep on getting this error and I don't know what to do with this. I use VIm8

```
x YouCompleteMe:
    Cloning into '/home/adib/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe'...
    
    
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

```
adib@adib-Inspiron-15-3552:~$ ls -ld ~/.vim/plugged
drwxr-xr-x 8 adib adib 4096 Aug 13 21:51 /home/adib/.vim/plugged
adib@adib-Inspiron-15-3552:~$ cd  /home/adib/.vim/plugged
adib@adib-Inspiron-15-3552:~/.vim/plugged$ ls
gruvbox  typescript-vim  undotree  vim-fugitive  vim-man  vim-rtags
adib@adib-Inspiron-15-3552:~/.vim/plugged$ cd
adib@adib-Inspiron-15-3552:~$ find ~/.vim ! -user adib -ls
adib@adib-Inspiron-15-3552:~$
```

some of ~/.vimrc file

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
Plug 'jremmen/vimripgrep'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'
Plug 'vim-utils/vim-man'
Plug 'lyuts/vim-rtags'
Plug 'mbbill/undotree'
Plug 'Adib234/ctrlp.vim'
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
call plug#end()
```

Full log of error

```
[======xxxx]

- Finishing ... Done!
x vimripgrep:
    Cloning into '/home/adib/.vim/plugged/vimripgrep'...
    fatal: 'git@github.comjremmen/vimripgrep.git' does not appear to be a git repository
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
- vim-fugitive: Already installed
x ctrlp.vim:
    Cloning into '/home/adib/.vim/plugged/ctrlp.vim'...
    fatal: 'git@github.comAdib234/ctrlp.vim.git' does not appear to be a git repository
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
x YouCompleteMe:
    Cloning into '/home/adib/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe'...
    fatal: 'git@github.comValloric/YouCompleteMe.git' does not appear to be a git repository
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
- vim-man: Already installed
- vim-rtags: Already installed
x nerdtree:
    Cloning into '/home/adib/.vim/plugged/nerdtree'...
    fatal: 'git@github.comscrooloose/nerdtree.git' does not appear to be a git repository
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
- typescript-vim: Already installed
- gruvbox: Already installed
- undotree: Already installed
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you check whether the directories have the correct permissions? Try `ls -ld ~/.vim`, then `ls -ld ~/.vim/plugged`, and so on for all directories in the path. Also interesting is `find ~/.vim ! -user adib -ls`. Please [edit] the question to post the answers to these follow up questions.

Comment: Questions answered

Answer (score 2):

The mistake in my case was that in my `~/.gitconfig` file, instead of having Git clone through `https` it would rewrite all clone request to `ssh`. I simply commented out the following lines to allow Git to clone through `https` again and to prevent it from rewriting.

```bash
#[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
#  insteadOf = https://github.com/
#[url "ssh://git@gitlab.com/"]
#  insteadOf = https://gitlab.com/
#[url "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/"]
#  insteadOf = https://bitbucket.org/
```

For more information on this please read [the following](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf).